# Typescript in Redux Saga : Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'. TS2339

Tags: typescript, react-redux

When I went to get the value from this API END point useing promises i am getting this type issues.

```
export function* signUpWithEmail(authInfo: any) {
const { email, password } = authInfo.payload

try {
    const response = yield authSignUpService
        .register(email, password)
        .then((res) => console.log(res))

    yield put(signUpSuccess(response))
} catch (error) {
    yield put(signUpFailure({ msg: error.message }))
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
authSignUpService
    .register(email, password)
```

is not is of type `Promise`. so, you cannot use `then()` function.